# Angular 4 get data from github api

Tags: json, angular, typescript, github-api

I trying getting my last commit from github. I used for this github api.
But I get error:

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."
```

I can getting data from simple json, and I used service and code like below, but now this not work for me.
Link to json:
[JSON](https://api.github.com/repos/objectprogr/Dashboard/git/commits/c3f9aabc6d3afa30dab3cccbfee592c096da9195)
If I getteing data from this [JSON](https://api.github.com/repos/objectprogr/Dashboard/git/refs), then I don't getting error, and I display what I want.

My githubservice:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { IpostsGithub } from './ipostsGithub'
@Injectable()
export class GithubService {

  private _postsURL = "https://api.github.com/repos/objectprogr/Dashboard/git/refs/heads/v1";


  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }

  getPosts(): Observable<IpostsGithub[]> {
      return this.http
          .get(this._postsURL)
          .map((response: Response) => {
              return <IpostsGithub[]>response.json();

          })     
  }

  private handleError(error: Response) {
      return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
  }

}
```

github component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GithubService } from './github.service';
import { IpostsGithub } from './ipostsGithub';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-github',
  templateUrl: './github.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./github.component.css'],
  providers: [ GithubService]
})
export class GithubComponent implements OnInit {

  _postsArray: IpostsGithub[];
  user: string;
  constructor(private githubService: GithubService, ) {
  }
  getPost(): void {
    this.githubService.getPosts()
        .subscribe(
            resultArray => this._postsArray= resultArray,
            error => console.log("Error :: " + error)
        )
}


ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPost();
}
}
```

And html:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <th>1</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let post of _postsArray">
      <td>{{post.message}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is code from error which I getting and, which I found o browser console:

```
_postsArray: […]
0: {…}
object: {…}
sha: "f0814bea75841ef7488552d29c6e1b8ad849f558"
type: "commit"
url: "https://api.github.com/repos/objectprogr/Dashboard/git/commits/f0814bea75841ef7488552d29c6e1b8ad849f558"
__proto__: Object { … }
ref: "refs/heads/v1"
url: "https://api.github.com/repos/objectprogr/Dashboard/git/refs/heads/v1"
```

And I dont have idea, how to fixed it?

Comment: Have you tried putting the async pipe ' | async ' in <tr *ngFor="let post of _postsArray"> after the _postsArray?

Comment: I don't understand. How would it look like?

Comment: When you console.log(resultArray), what does the result look like?

Comment: {
  "ref": "refs/heads/v1",
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/objectprogr/Dashboard/git/refs/heads/v1",
  "object": {
    "sha": "46a39895c556980a0b00353a2eb330dd8e0a8d12",
    "type": "commit",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/objectprogr/Dashboard/git/commits/46a39895c556980a0b00353a2eb330dd8e0a8d12"
  }
}

Comment: What if you try to put that result object into an array like this: this._postsArray= [resultArray], . Just change the line in your code with what I put

Comment: I changed resultArray => this._postsArray= [resultArray], and I must change _postArry to any[] beacuse I getting error. But still i getting error

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the API returns an object of objects, ngFor only works with iterables such as an array.

Comment: Ok, but I still don't know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are getting an Object instead of an Array, and you want to loop over that? Correct me if I'm wrong.

If that's the case this is how you would go about it:

in your `.ts` file

```
    export class SomeClass {
    Object: Object;
    constructor() {
     ...
    }
}
```

In your `.html`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of Object.keys(yourObject); let i = index;">
    {{item}}={{yourObject[item]}}
</div>
```

Comment: But for which ts file I must add this code, and what add to constructor?

Comment: The Object: Object bit in your github component, and the loop in your html component.. the one where you loop the _postsArray

Comment: If I add everything well, it I getting error: "_co.Object is undefined". Github component: export class GithubComponent implements OnInit {

  _postsArray: any[];
  Object: Object;
  constructor(private githubService: GithubService, ) {
  }
  getPost(): void {
    this.githubService.getPosts()
        .subscribe(
            resultArray => this._postsArray= [resultArray],
            error => console.log("Error :: " + error)
            
        )   
}

Comment: Try adding this in your github component before the constructor instead of Object: Object
------------------
objectKeys = Object.keys;

and then in your HTML file

*ngFor="let item of objectKeys(yourObject)"

Comment: Now I getting: "can't convert undefined to object"

Comment: Well first off the Data you are getting back is not an array, so _postsArray:any[] will not be a valid type for the data. Second, check what is undefined in this case.

Comment: How I can check what is undefined? I find this in browser console?

Comment: Ok, I check in console, and: This is _postArray: postsArray: […]
0: {…}
object: {…}
sha: "f0814bea75841ef7488552d29c6e1b8ad849f558"
type: "commit"
url: "https://api.github.com/repos/objectprogr/Dashboard/git/commits/f0814bea75841ef7488552d29c6e1b8ad849f558"
__proto__: Object { … }
ref: "refs/heads/v1"
url: "https://api.github.com/repos/objectprogr/Dashboard/git/refs/heads/v1"
__proto__: Object { … }. So, _postArry have all information from json. This is how to display them? And this is objectKeys: keys()
name: "keys"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166947/discussion-between-filipbarak-and-objectprogr).